# JPA Facet cannot be activated in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jpa, facet

If I try to activate the "JPA Facet" for my Eclipse (Juno) project and point it to a user library containing the JPA libraries (in my case OpenJPA) I get the error:

*"The class 'javax.persistence.Entity' is required to be in the selected libraries."*

But this class is present there!

Answer (score 4):

**"Solution":** The JPA libraries were contained in an Eclipse  project folder. If I copy it somewhere outside and create another user library with them it works perfectly (although it has exactly the same content as the one before with the libraries located in the Eclipse project!). Seems like an Eclipse bug...

Answer (score 1):

Just create a user library that contains the javax.persistence... JAR in it (It is located in Eclipse/plugins) and add this library at "JPA Implementation"

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Spring Tool Suite (STS). The problem I was facing is that in the default installation the M2E-WTP plugin does not include the Optional component *"m2e-wtp - JPA Configurator for WTP"*.
So I went to `Help -> Eclipse Marketplace...` and searched "m2e-wtp".

[image]

Click on the *Installed* button and it will become *Change*. Click on the *Change* button and select the optional component *"m2e-wtp - JPA Configurator for WTP"*. Apply changes.

This solved for me.